# How to modify data grid view columns with data table bindings

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have binded `DataTable` to `DataGridView` (in WinForms) and i'd like to change how columns are formatted in GUI.

However, if i manually add columns to `DataGridView` and set `errorsGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false`, data doesn't appear in those columns (rows are added however). So is there any way to bind `DataTable` and change eg. width of column in `DataGridView`? With `AutoGenerateColumns = false` bindings like `BingingList` are added to existing columns, but `DataTable` doesn't seem to work that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please tell have you specified `DataPropertyName` attribute for each of columns you have added manually on **Edit Columns** form for your grid (as on screenshot below)?

[image]

Looks like you need to specify binding to table columns explicitly for each of your grid columns on form **Edit Columns** which is invoked by right-click menu item **Edit Columns...** for grid view in form editor. You need to configure data binding for each column manually, as you have specified grid's property `errorsGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false` (which means columns with bidings to table fields will not be generated automatically). As grid contains empty rows - you can be sure that data is loaded successfully, and the only thing which remains to do - is to configure way how rows are displayed in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best way to handle datagridview formatting when bound data source is to apply it AFTER the binding.  You would need to reference the column either by index or by the table column name.